# Transfer metadata related to Image overlay in Google Earth pro from one system to another?

Tags: overlay, google-earth-pro

I have been working on Google Earth pro desktop software and have overlayed many JPG images over it.

Every time I close and open the software again, the images remain intact in there correct positions so most probably some meta data is being stored by the software to control the position,size and other aspects related to Overlayed images.

Now I want to shift to some other Machine (new laptop) but I don't want to set the positions, size and rotation angles of all the overlayed images again in my new laptop.

Is there some easy work around such that I can transfer all this information to my new laptop easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each layer of **Image overlays** can be saved as **kmz** file. First, right-click on the layer to activate a context menu, then select `Save Place As...` option.

[image]

You can save it as **kmz** file, which bundles both of your image and location information. (Below: Top left icon in a red rectangle). Copy this `kmz` file to your new laptop and double-click on this icon. The image will show up at the exact location where you had it.

In case you want to visually check its location (or extent), choose **kml** option. You will have both `kml` and `Untitled.png` image. (Below: icons on the left in an orange rectangle). Open the kml file by a text editor. (Below: right hand side).

[image]